# Unable to connect to oracle for java8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, apt

I've been working with setting up a few servers over the past week using Ansible. Everything has been humming along fine until today a couple of hours ago the java8 playbook I had been using quit working randomly. I haven't touched it or looked at it in weeks. I even did `git checkout` to a known working version, still doesn't work.

The problem is almost verbatim the same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815897/jdk-8-is-not-installed-error-404-not-found where I'm getting a 404 every time I try to run `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`. It also tries to download java8 on other commands like `sudo apt autoremove` and I always see the same error -

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1531861842_cbe60a307e0051ef681fa0cef4e500ce [following]
--2018-07-17 21:08:42--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1531861842_cbe60a307e0051ef681fa0cef4e500ce
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.40.18.106|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-07-17 21:08:42 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried everything listed in the SO question above and many other solutions I found elsewhere. I'm beginning to think my IP is blocked or oracle is having some issues on their end, am I missing something?

Comment: Look at that URL in a web browser, and you will have your answer.

Comment: Yeah I just hit the same route from Postman on my local and got a 200 code, it must be blocked

Comment: Can you just go with java9?  Do you really need java8?

Comment: @Zoredache I'm sure java9 will work for what I need, but unless Oracle started making java8 unavailable a couple of hours ago I dont think its that. I think I probably just hit my quota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having that same error as well. Until the people at WebUpd8 update their package you need to edit it yourself. I used the answer you linked to, just with the new data:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u171|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_171|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="b6dd2837efaaec4109b36cfbb94a774db100029f98b0d78be68c27bec0275982"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Is there any reason for not using the official open source openjdk-8-jdk package instead of the one from oracle?

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Should work if you are on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04.
The task for Ansible in this case is quite easy:

```
- name: Install openjdk-8-jdk
  action: apt pkg=openjdk-8-jdk state=installed
```

For versions prior to Ubuntu 16.04 (which I would only use 14.04, the others are EOL) you could use [Matthias PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Regarding Ansible, for this last case, you can add the repo as a task like this:

```
- hosts: your-server
  tasks:
    - name: install repo for Java 8 in Ubuntu 14.04 or below
      apt_repository: repo='ppa:openjdk-r/ppa'
```

Comment: I got it working with openjdk too before @glennsmith's answer, both worked.

Comment: The difference with the method from @glen is that it seems you are fixing the java version with those edits. You might not get security updates that way. Being java, I would advise you choose the repository option, as to allow for upgrades in case of security releases. Glad both versions worked any way!! Regards.